# One word for "Plus Tard"

Tags: choix-de-mot, informatique, terminologie

I'm trying to create a system of one-word tags for a software application. Some of the tags include "archives", "thémes", "brouillons", and "poubelle". I need a tag that symbolizes "À lire plus tard", so I'm looking for a single word that signifies "plus tard". Some ideas I've had that I don't like are:

- Tardif
- Après
- Futur

Is there anything that approaches "plus tard" more precisely?

Comment: I can't think of a single word that I'd understand in this context. Why insist on a single word? Several two-word phrases would work.

Comment: Very true... je n'insiste pas. Single words work well as tabs but "plus tard" may be the best available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These words do not carry the same meanings.

- tardif: a late arrival
- après: after something
- futur: the future (the era)

But, "Ultérieurement" litteray means "plus tard"

Comment: +1 for hitting it on the head with ultérieurement, which is a mouthful for an application tag. I'm going to see if anything shorter crops up, otherwise will mark this as answer.

Comment: There are at http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tard, c), some explanations about _plus tard_; confirms _ultérieurement_, and also _différer_, and _après_.

Comment: @ChrisSchiffhauer *Ultérieurement* may be a single word, but I don't think I'd understand it in context.